# Java - search text with a length of 100 million characters+?

Tags: java

I want to search a text document (or multiple text documents) where the character count will total up to potentially 100 million characters+.

I'm using Java, is there an easy way to go around this without using too much memory?
It'll be running on an Android device, so I want to use as little memory as possible.

I could just the String functions such as `if(source.contains(phrase)){}`. I've calculated that it doesn't take very long to calculate but uses a lot of memory.

Here are some results:
String to search for?

```
"FADE OUT."
312,719 - source length.
62,543,800 - source length multiplied by 200.
1) Phrase found in 6 ms - searched 312,719 characters. Used 261 mb.
2) Phrase found in 1 ms - searched 625,447 characters. Used 269 mb.
3) Phrase found in 0 ms - searched 1,250,903 characters. Used 284 mb.
4) Phrase found in 0 ms - searched 2,501,815 characters. Used 315 mb.
5) Phrase found in 0 ms - searched 5,003,639 characters. Used 33 mb.
6) Phrase found in 0 ms - searched 1,0007,287 characters. Used 159 mb.
7) Phrase found in 0 ms - searched 20,014,583 characters. Used 114 mb.
8) Phrase found in 0 ms - searched 40,029,175 characters. Used 229 mb.
9) Phrase found in 0 ms - searched 80,058,359 characters. Used 763 mb.
10) Phrase found in 0 ms - searched 160,116,727 characters. Used 916 mb.
```

The source length is the average size of a text file I'm searching. I multiplied it by 200 to get an average of how big 200 text files will be.

So how can I search a text file without using so much ram?

Comment: Hadoop Map Reduce.  http://hadoop.apache.org/

Comment: If there is no natural subdivision into lines or similar, where your target string can never span two lines, then you'll need extra logic to take care of what happens at the edges of the chunks you read in. If there *is* such a subdivision, then the problem becomes a trivial one-liner.

Comment: I would recommend to not do this on the device. This is a task for a server and / or a good database. You want to have a look at Hadoop.

Comment: Are you putting all the text into memory. Surely read it in a stream with something like a BufferedReader?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't roll my own search algorithm if I wanted high performance over a large chunk of text. There are plenty out there that were designed to deal with it. And if you're allowed to index your content, they're blazingly fast and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple algorithm similar a little to the [RabinKarp](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html) (RabinKarp is much more efficient but of course much more complex) Method `find` returns the index of the first occurrence of provided phrase.([code](https://github.com/ssledz/stackoverflow-answers/blob/master/stackoverflow-java-answers/src/main/java/pl/softech/stackoverflow/search/SearchForPhrase.java))

```
public class SearchForPhrase {

    static int hash(String phrase) {
        int hash = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            hash += phrase.codePointAt(i);
        }
        return hash;
    }

    static boolean equals(Deque<Character> txt, String phrase) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Character c : txt) {
            if (!c.equals(phrase.charAt(i++))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static int find(String phrase, Reader in) throws Exception {

        int phash = hash(phrase);
        int hash;

        BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(in);
        char[] buffer = new char[phrase.length()];

        int readed = bin.read(buffer);

        if (readed < phrase.length()) {
            return -1;
        }

        String tmp = new String(buffer);
        hash = hash(tmp);
        if (hash == phash && tmp.equals(phrase)) {
            return 0;
        }

        Deque<Character> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        for (char c : buffer) {
            queue.add(c);
        }

        int curr;
        int index = 1;
        while ((curr = bin.read()) != -1) {

            hash = hash - queue.removeFirst() + curr;
            queue.add((char) curr);

            if (hash == phash && equals(queue, phrase)) {
                return index;
            }

            index++;

        }

        return -1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
        out.println("Discuss the person's qualifications for the graduate study in the chosen field. Statements of past");
        out.println("performance, accomplishments, and contributions are helpful. The more relevant the items mentioned, andd");
        out.flush();

        System.out
                .println(find("Discuss", new StringReader(writer.toString())));
        System.out.println(find("the", new StringReader(writer.toString())));
        System.out.println(find("qualifications",
                new StringReader(writer.toString())));
        System.out.println(find("andd", new StringReader(writer.toString())));

    }

}
```

Out:

```
0
8
21
199
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `InputStream` (or `Reader`) to read your code, thats what Streams generally are for. In this case, use a list of chars with the length of your search string to read the chars in, and discard every char you don't need anymore. You could do it something like this:

```
Reader in = new Reader(...);
String searchStr = "search string";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(searchStr.length());
// start reading
char read;
while ((read = in.read()) != -1)
{
    if (sb.length() == searchStr.length()) sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    sb.append(read);
    if (sb.toString().equals(searchStr))
    {
        System.out.println("Match found!");
        break; // stop reading if you only need one match
    }
}
```

The only memory allocated for this will be `searchStr.length() * 2`, so if you don't have a very long search string, you don't need much memory.

Comment: The only problem is the inefficiency of reading char by char. At least you should use a `BufferedReader`, but you'll still be making 100 million `in.read()` calls. You'll also be doing a heavy lot of redundant string comparisons. And you'll be generating a huge number of ephemeral string objects, which will push the CG overhead.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've never said that the performace is good, but if you know a better way, tell the asker.

Comment: Another problem is the deleteCharAt() call, which forces the StringBuilder to constantly create array copies to move all the characters to the beginning